# How to indicate the position in a class within an if statement?

Tags: java, android

I want to evaluate my position within a java class and from that run some code using an if statement.

This is part of my code in Android Studio

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PictureViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        PictureListPizza pictureListPizza = pictureListPizzas.get(position);
        holder.product_name.setText(pictureListPizza.getProduct_name());
        holder.product_ingredients.setText(pictureListPizza.getProduct_ingredients());
        holder.product_price.setText(pictureListPizza.getProduct_price());
        Picasso.with(activity).load(pictureListPizza.getPicture()).into(holder.product_photo);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (PizzaActivity.class != null){
                    if(position == 0){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Pizza1Activity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if(position == 1){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Pizza2Activity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if(position == 2){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Pizza3Activity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

`

As you can see I am placing if (PizzaActivity. class! = null){} but I know it is wrong.

It's for an android project.

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Greetings.

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: If I am not wrong You Need Position Outside your Adapter ?? right?? or You want tu Use your Listener  Outside adapter Class??

Comment: if PizzaActivity.class is your activity, then you can use getActivity() method

Comment: This question is not clear. Please state *what* is the problem, you only showed us some code and didn't provide a question...

Comment: " I want to evaluate my position within a java class "  You need to describe what you want better than this.  Position within a class isn't a thing.  I can make a few guesses on what you actually meant, but I have no idea what you actually mean.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onBindViewHolder` method like this:

```
  .....
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     // no neeed this condition
                    //if (PizzaActivity.class != null){
                    if(position == 0){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Pizza1Activity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if(position == 1){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Pizza2Activity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if(position == 2){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Pizza3Activity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        });
```

Hope it'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting position as a tag in `holder.itemView` 
and in `onClick()` method, use `view.getTag()` to retrieve same position and act accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Class don't check null. If you want check exists class, you can refer:

```
public boolean isClass(String className) {
    try  {
        Class.forName(className);
        return true;
    }  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
if (isClass("android.app.ActionBar")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I hope it can help your problem!